# If greater than batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I wrote a simple batch file to run Frequently Used websites based on a number selection. Here's the code I have. I am trying to set it so if someone inputs a number 6 or greater it will go to `:N` but whenever I type 6 the batch file exits. I have tried `if %input% > 6 goto :N` but it just tells me I am going to Google.

```
@echo off
:Start2 
cls
goto Start
:Start
title Frequently Used Websites
echo Please select a website from the list
echo with the corresponding key
echo --------------------------------------
echo [1] Google
echo [2] Wikipedia
echo [3] Facebook
echo [4] Youtube
echo [5] Yahoo
set input=
set /p input= Choice:
if %input%==1 goto Z if NOT goto Start2
if %input%==2 goto X if NOT goto Start2
if %input%==3 goto C if NOT goto Start2
if %input%==4 goto V if NOT goto Start2
if %input%==5 goto B if NOT goto Start2
if %input%>=6 goto N

:Z
cls
echo You have selected Google
pause
start www.google.com
exit
:X
cls
echo You have selected Wikipedia
pause
start www.wikipedia.com
exit
:C
cls
echo You have selected Facebook
pause
start www.facebook.com
exit
:V
cls
echo You have selected Youtube
pause
start www.youtube.com
exit
:B
cls
echo You have selected Yahoo
pause
start www.Yahoo.com
exit
:N
cls
echo Invalid Selection! Try again
pause
goto :start2
```

Comment: Since the only time it will ever arrive on the line `if %input%>=6 goto N` is when it's >=6, you could just drop the if, and write `goto N`.

Comment: Try `if /?` and it would help you

Answer (score 122, accepted):

try this:

```
if 3 gtr 2 @echo "biggger"
```

This outputs:

```
"biggger"
```

[image]

The other operators are:

> EQU - equal
> NEQ - not equal
> LSS - less than
> LEQ - less than or equal
> GTR - greater than
> GEQ - greater than or equal

#### Reference

- Microsoft TechNet | Windows Server 2012 | [Command-line Reference: If](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754335) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/59JyL))
- [SS64: If](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/XvIoR))

Answer (score 9):

```
    if %var% geq 1
```

is the easiest way

Comment: Two year old question with good accepted answer. Try to make answer which really adds something new, with more content.

Comment: Actually this answer is a bit different. Accepted answer compares two constants. This one at least shows a variable use. For those who can not differentiate between `var` and `%var%` it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't even need a greater feature. All you need to do is add

```
goto homepagename
```

Then you will be taken there if none of the if commands execute a goto command.

For example, this will fix your code:

```
@echo off
:Start2 
cls
goto Start
:Start
title Frequently Used Websites
echo Please select a website from the list
echo with the corresponding key
echo --------------------------------------
echo [1] Google
echo [2] Wikipedia
echo [3] Facebook
echo [4] Youtube
echo [5] Yahoo
set input=
set /p input= Choice:
if %input%==1 goto Z if NOT goto Start2
if %input%==2 goto X if NOT goto Start2
if %input%==3 goto C if NOT goto Start2
if %input%==4 goto V if NOT goto Start2
if %input%==5 goto B if NOT goto Start2
if %input%>=6 goto N
goto Start
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this (easier)

```
@echo off

:Start2
cls
goto Start

:Start
title Frequently Used Websites
echo Please select a website from the list
echo with the corresponding key
echo --------------------------------------
echo [1] Google
echo [2] Wikipedia
echo [3] Facebook
echo [4] Youtube
echo [5] Yahoo

set /p input= Choice: 

if %input%==1 goto Z
if %input%==2 goto X
if %input%==3 goto C
if %input%==4 goto V
if %input%==5 goto B
echo Invalid selection!
echo.
echo Press any key to go back!
pause >nul
cls
goto start2

:Z
cls
echo You have selected Google
pause
start www.google.com
exit

:X
cls
echo You have selected Wikipedia
pause
start www.wikipedia.com
exit

:C
cls
echo You have selected Facebook
pause
start www.facebook.com
exit

:V
cls
echo You have selected Youtube
pause
start www.youtube.com
exit

:B
cls
echo You have selected Yahoo
pause
start www.Yahoo.com
exit

:N
cls
echo Invalid Selection! Try again
pause
goto start2
```

Comment: @TLama, as far as I was aware, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/bdc9691d-6963-4b70-9db2-2b8e582a3e91/view-source) was his posting, which appeared to be new lines during the review (perhaps my suggestion should have been rejected). Regardless, the answer needs formatting. If it's a one line statement, it should be one line, not a large paragraph.